# How to use preg_match properly to accept characters including new lines?

Tags: php, regex

I've tried to use a series of questions to construct a preg_match if statement to check a string and make sure it includes characters that are accepted to pass through the system.

I've got the following if statement;

```
if ( !preg_match("~[A-Za-z0-9-_=+,.:;/\!?%^&*()@#\"\'£\$€ ]~", $data['text']) ) {}
```

I'm using ~ as a separator in the string and want to ensure that the above characters are accepted in whatever string is passed through.

I've had to escape " and ' quotes and the $ sign to ensure it doesn't break the statement.

It seems to work however the following doesn't work.

```
Hello, this is a single line. Don't you agree?

This is also another line, see?
```

After some trial and error, it seemed the comma was also causing the string check to fail but it's in the preg_match rule too.

How can I accept these characters `A-Za-z0-9-_=+,.:;/\!?%^&*()@#\"\'£\$€` as well as multi lines (line blank lines, spaces etc etc).

**EDIT**

Just an update as to what I enter in the textarea and what data is actually returned.

I entered the following in the textarea;

```
Testing 123

Testing 123
```

The following was returned using print_r;

```
Testing 123\r\n\r\nTesting 1231
```

Comment: Replace the last space in the character class with `\s` to match any kind of whitespace.

Comment: If you need to match ASCII only, you can use  `~^[[:ascii:]]+$~` or - if you do not want to match the entire string - `~[[:ascii:]]+~`

Comment: I just want to match the following but it doesn't seem to work still. I'm using `if ( !preg_match("~[A-Za-z0-9-_=+,.:;/\!?%^&*()@#\"\'£\$€\s]~", $data['text']) {}` and it's falling still. If it is okay it makes the value of a variable false, or if it fails it makes the variable true which shows a custom error.

Comment: Ok, am I right you are trying to check for ASCII symbols only? Try `if (!preg_match('~[[:ascii:]]~', $data['text'])) {}`. Where does `$data['text']` come from, BTW? Maybe you need `'~[[:ascii:]]~u'`. And another thing: maybe you have `<br>` there instead of a linebreak?

Comment: The $data['text'] comes from a textarea that I put through mysqli_real_escape_string first, then the value is put through this check. I tried both ascii versions and still not use. The input I use is `Hello and Hello` with a blank line in between them.

Comment: Do the regex check before escaping. Look: [*Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Is the last `1` at the end of `print_r` a typo or is it really present?

Comment: That's really there, it seems to have come from the mysqli real escape function I think.

Comment: This seems to work, does it matter about having the \s and then a space at the end? `if ( !preg_match("~[^A-Za-z0-9-_=+,.:;/\!?%^&*()@#\"\'£\$€\s ]~s", $data['text']) ) {}`

Comment: No, `\s` also matches a space, there is no sense using both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another look at your question and there is actually two issues:

1. The regex misses a character to accept any kind of spaces, you should update it to `~[A-Za-z0-9-_=+,.:;/\!?%^&*()@#\"\'£\$€\s]+~` here I replaced your space character at the end with `\s` so that it supports any kind of spaces (i.e. tabs, newline, etc)
2. You forgot to escape the input string from `$data['text']` which you can do using `stripcslashes`.

After fixing those you still need to validate your input, to do so you can use `preg_replace` to create a new string that will contain all the invalid characters if there is any. From there you only need to check if the string is empty, if so then the input is valid.

Here is what I used to test this:

```
<?php

$data = 'Testing 123\r\n\r\nTesting 1231';

$unescaped_data = stripcslashes($data);

$impureData = preg_replace("~[A-Za-z0-9-_=+,.:;/\!?%^&*()@#\"\'£\$€\s]+~", 
    '', $unescaped_data);

if (0 == strlen($impureData)) {
    echo 'TRUE';
}
else {
    echo 'FALSE';
}

print_r("
====
$data
====
$impureData
====
");
```

And I get this result:

```
TRUE
====
Testing 123\r\n\r\nTesting 1231
====

====
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why.

Comment: Also why the -1 on a perfectly valid answer that solves the question ?

Comment: @IamNguele: `\s` does not just match "spaces". Also, your solution is unreadable and hard to maintain. And last but not least, the regex makes little sense for now, when OP has not defined any specs. Now, even `~.+~s` can be a valid answer.

Comment: I replied simply to not make a huge sentence only to reply a relatively simple question. And added a link explaining how the metacharacter \s solves his issue and what it matches. So I don't get the salt here.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I pasted the code in as is above.

Comment: Can you try to debug what's in `$data['text']` using print_r ? like this `print_r($data['text'])`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This seems to work for me thanks, one of my issues was also the fact I was escaping the string before doing the character check.